How can I optimize my table better with 130 million rows of data?
I have a consumers table with name, email, identity number, contact and address. There are columns such as unit, street, postcode and more but not used. All the columns has been indexed and address is full text index. I have no issue querying name, email, identity number and contact with less than a second. But I can't seem to run the address. I'm using MATCH() AGAINST () sometimes it can run, sometimes it says the table handler ran out of memory. And I can't seem to find a better solution to optimize it. Any help? Do ignore the unit, street, area, _raw_address and more, I'm still trying to optimize the table. The contact, _contact and __contact are valid as those are contact, contact 2 and contact 3. I just noticed the data is only 20GB while the index itself is 30GB. I need help to optimize my database. My main problem now is I cant search on the address field at all.
 `CREATE TABLE `consumers` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `fullname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `contact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `_contact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `__contact` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nric` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
 `unit` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `street` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `area` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `postcode` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
 `raw_address` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `_raw_address` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `__raw_address` text DEFAULT NULL,
 `source` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
 `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
 `created_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `fullname` (`fullname`),
 KEY `nric` (`nric`),
 KEY `_contact` (`_contact`),
 KEY `contact` (`contact`),
 KEY `__contact` (`__contact`),
 KEY `unit` (`unit`),
 KEY `city` (`city`),
 KEY `street` (`street`),
 KEY `state` (`state`),
 KEY `postcode` (`postcode`),
 KEY `source` (`source`),
 KEY `email` (`email`),
 KEY `area` (`area`),
 KEY `country` (`country`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `raw_address` (`raw_address`),
 FULLTEXT KEY `_raw_address` (`_raw_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=180871031 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci

Query I am using now for address is
SELECT * FROM consumers WHERE MATCH(raw_address) AGAINST ('SOMETEXT' IN BOOLEAN MODE) LIMIT 10


All the columns has been indexed, not quite right. Indexes are build based on the query used. If they speed up data retrieval it has the oposite effect during inserts/updates etc. Address and all the related columns should be in a differet table . To proper give you an answer please add the output of show create table consumers , post the query and execution plan of the query you are having difficulties  all in text format

@ErgestBasha Hey man thanks for responding. I just added the code to my question. Hope this gives more info.

I was thinking about separating the table for address so i can partition it and can directly search on the partition table depending on the first few characters. But at the same time I noticed the user might want to search a word that is inside the address not necessarily starting with the word. So I am currently still sticking with this design and yet to come up with a better design.

make obe or multiple combined inde4xe4s

I’m not sure if clustered index is going to help because I will be only searching one column everytime. So it’s either name, contact, email, identity number or address. As mentioned I have no issue searching the rest except address

You still have not shown any SQL query you want to optimize.

@BillKarwin Hi, I've added the query in the question. Thanks for responding.

I have read about a defect in MySQL that fails to deallocate memory used by fulltext search. Details here: https://www.percona.com/blog/mysql-memory-management-memory-allocators-and-operating-system/. But I don't know a solution. The bug is still not fixed.

RIP me. Then I probably can't use MATCH AGAINST anymore then. I am thinking to split the addresses into units, streets, streetnumber, postcode, city, country and then filter based on those. I believe it might be faster. Perhaps I could create a table to store the distinct list of cities once user selected the state to enhance performance
